# Looping through identically named datasets

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I want to loop and create nearly indentically named datasets. I have the datasets `df.1` and `df.2` to start with and the following command keeps failing:

```
for (x in 1:2) {
        df.x
        }
```

What I am trying to do is create an amortization table. This seemed relatively easy enough to do with `for` loops, but everyone seems to suggest tables for when indexing dataframes. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can work this? I am very unfamiliar with `lapply` or any `list` functions.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off scraping your workspace manually or through `ls()` to find the data.frames, put them in a list and work from there.

```
x <- 1:5
y <- letters[x]
z <- c(T, T, T, T, F)

# put the elements into a list
your.list <- lapply(ls(), FUN = get)

# calculate length of each list element
lapply(your.list, FUN = length)

# anonymous function
lapply(your.list, FUN = function(bla) {
    if (is.numeric(bla)) {
        return(sum(bla))
    } else {
        return(NA)
    }
})
```

Needless to say, you are not limited to vectors, this works for any object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit specific to Roman Luštrik's answer. Select his if helpful.

```
df.1 <- data.frame(var = c(1,2))
df.2 <- data.frame(var = c(2,3))

for(i in 1:2) {
    data <- get(paste("df.",i,sep=""))
    print(data)
}
  var
1   1
2   2
  var
1   2
2   3
```